# Div width and height does not fit the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]I am trying to change the color of a transparent image inside a div (using jQuery). I cannot get the left and top of the image fixed into the div while changing the color.

Could anyone help? I'm trying to have the image filled if a user clicks on any of the span colors.

**test.css:**

```
.iconWrapper .color span
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 58px;
    display: block;
}
.color1
{
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.color2
{
    background-color: #ffe25b;
}
.color3
{
    background-color: #e35990;
}
.color4
{
    background-color: #58c1d8;
}
```

**step1.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" media="screen" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.iconWrapper span').click(function(e){
        var color=$(this).attr('class');
            //alert(color);
            $('#div1').removeClass().addClass(color);
            $('#hiddencolor').val(color);
            e.preventDefault();
        });    
    });    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="iconWrapper">
        <ul class="color">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color1"></span></a>                               
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Selecteer "><span class="color2" ></span></a>                               
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color3"></span></a>                               
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Selecteer"><span class="color4"></span></a>                               
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="div1" style="width:17%; height:28%;" ><img src="img/107.png" />
    <form method="post" action="step3.php">
        <input name="kleur" type="text" value="" id="hiddencolor" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>   
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the full path of your image, and elaborate a little bit more what you want to happen when you do what, because from your code it's not clear (at least to me) what you want to achieve.

Comment: you're welcome: http://jsfiddle.net/V9zEH/

Comment: @ANeves: Thanks, but no thanks. I already had one created, but the image and the explanation as to what should happen and when.

Comment: @Shef: from my point of view, posting a clean working example is inarguably more helpful than posting a page of code. The less time people need to spend understanding your problem the more time they will have left to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $('.iconWrapper span').click(function (e) {
        var $span = $(this),
            color = $span.attr('class');
        $('#div1 img').css('background-color', $span.css('background-color'));

        $('#hiddencolor').val(color);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Test the effect here »](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/RetC9/)

Comment: i want to have  only the image colored not the div around it. The color should not spells out of the circle(image ) .I am not sure if i am doing this in the right way or if there is this possibility.

Comment: @Mary: The only way to do it, is if you use a totally white cut-through PNG (reversed transparency), so when you change the background color it will show. [Take a look at the updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/RetC9/) (my cut-through is horrible, but it's just for context, of course you can make it very precise).

Comment: well pretty nice but it would be great to have the whole image filled with the color not only the borders. Anyhow it gives me some idea how to go further. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Change the width of the parent div from `17%` to the `width` of `img` in other words `250px`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V9zEH/5/

Comment: i want only image gets filled with the color not the div around it. this width and height(<div id="div1" style="width:17%; height:28%;" ><img src="img/107.png" width="250px"height="200px") work fine only if you guys help me how to get the left and top of color fit into the image. hope that is clear

Answer (score 1):

```
        $('#div1 img').removeClass().addClass(color);
```

Would this be what you wanted?

If what you want is the color to not spill out of the borders inside the image, the only solution I can find is to edit the image so that there is white where you don't want to see the colour - rather than transparent.

I have trouble understanding what it is exactly that you want to achieve. :|

Comment: _"The problem was that your click handler was being defined inside a function that was never called."_ Wrong. [`$(handler)` is a shorthand version of `$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I stand absolutely corrected. Let me try to figure out what was wrong, then. :)

Comment: Meh. Turns out that the initial JSFiddle had no JQuery, so when I edited what I thought was a correction and added Jquery it seemed fixed. When in fact OP's question was totally different from what I thought it was. Meh, will revamp the answer. (Can't -1 myself? Curious.)

Comment: yea i want that the color not spills out of the borders of the image, Right(only image should turn red or blue ext).By editing the image, did you mean that i should change the size of the image or what?

Comment: I meant editing it in an image editor, like @Shef said. Making transparent the areas you want to change colour, and not transparent the areas you don't want to change colour.